# How to use Oracle's connect by clause in eclipselink?

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, eclipselink

According to Eclipselink documentation:

```
Expression startWith = builder.get("id").equal(new Integer(100));
//can be any expression which identifies a set of employees
Expression connectBy = builder.get("managedEmployees");
//indicated the relationship that the hierarchy is based on, must be self-referential
Vector orderBy = new Vector();
orderBy.addElement(builder.get("startDate"));
readAllQuery.setHierarchicalQueryClause(startWith, connectBy, orderBy);
```

I am not able to form ConnectBy expression.

I have used following expression:
`Expression connectBy = expressionBuilder.get("id").equal(expressionBuilder.get("parentId"));`

I m getting following error:
Exception Description: Malformed expression in query. Attempting to print an object reference into an SQL statement for query key

Can anyone help me how to use setHierarchicalQueryClause in eclipselink?

Comment: The example in the doc has an Employee->ManagedEmployees relationship defined in the entity, do you have one for your parent->Child relationship?

Comment: Yes.. The relationship was missing..I added and it worked.